# Bad state: cannot get a field on a DocumentSnapshotPlatform which does not exist, Receiver: null Tried calling: get("Name")

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

[image]I am trying to get the data of currently signed in user in profile screen of my app. Below is the code of getting the data of currently signed in user from the firebase. The field (Name) of which  it is showing error do exist in the firebase and all the data I am trying to get is stored in the firebase but it shows the following error anytime I try to get from the firebase. Kindly help me through this.

```
class Profile extends StatelessWidget {
  static const id = 'Profile';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid);
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.yellowAccent.shade700,
        leading: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
            child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back)),
        actions: [
          Icon(Icons.person),
        ],
      ),
      body: StreamBuilder<DocumentSnapshot>(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('Client_Data')
            .doc(FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
          //print('////${FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser.uid}');
          return Column(children: [
            Stack(
              children: [
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0, left: 20),
                  child: Container(
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      radius: 70,
                      child: ClipOval(
                        child: Image.asset(
                          'assets/images/Flutter.jpeg',
                          height: 140,
                          width: 140,
                          fit: BoxFit.fill,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 50,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ProfileContainers(
                title: 'Name',
                value: snapshot.data.get('Name'),
              ),
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 15,
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: ProfileContainers(
                title: 'Email',
                value: snapshot.data.get('Email'),
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: can you send a screenshot of the document in the firebase

Comment: @LMech I have edited the question with the screenshot.